# How multiple consumer can listen to multiple topic in spring boot Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am not able to listen the kafka topic (my case 2 topics) when there are multiple consumer. 
In below example, I am have 2 consumer factory which will be accpet 2 different JSON messages (one is user type and other is Event type). Both the messages are posted to different topic. Here when I am trying to access the Event messages from topic1, i am not able to but I can access the user topic messages.

Ex:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfiguration {      
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String,User> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("user.consumer.group"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonDeserializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(User.class));

}
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String , Event> consumerFactoryEvent(){
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("event.consumer.group"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonDeserializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(Event.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryEvent() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryEvent());
    return factory;
}
}
```

My main application is like below:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${event.topic}")
public void processEvent(Event event) {
..do something..
..post the message to User topic
}
@KafkaListener(topics = "${user.topic}")
public void processUser(User user) {
..do something..
}
```

My need is to listen the event topic first and do some massaging to the message and then send it the User topic and I have another method which will listen to the User topic and do something on that message.. 
I tried to pass different options to the @KafkaListener such as

```
@KafkaListener(topics="${event.topic}",containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactoryEvent")
```

but it is not working.. I am not sure whats going wrong.. any suggestion is helpful!

Comment: Try defining two different bean names for two listeners and add those names in '@kafkaListener' annotation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not specify name in bean then method name will be bean name, add bean name with groupid in `@KafkaListener`

```
@KafkaListener(topics="${event.topic}",containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactoryEvent", groupId="")

@KafkaListener(topics="${event.topic}",containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory", groupId="")
```

or

Specify name in `@Bean` and add that name to `@kafkaListener`

```
@Bean(name="kafkaListenerContainerFactoryEvent")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryEvent() {
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryEvent());
return factory;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

> It's not easily available in the any of the docs.
>
> Here I am taking the example of consuming the messages from
>
> **topic=topic1 with bootstrapserver=url1 (JSON Serializer and Deserializer)**
>
> **topic=topic2 with bootstrapserver=url2 (Avro Serializer and Deserializer)**

***Step1:-***

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory1() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "localhost1:9092"); //This is dummy
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory consumerFactory2() {
    Map props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "localhost2:9092"); //This is dummy
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put("schema.registry.url", "https://abc.schemaregistery.example.com"); //Again this is dummy or can be avro serilaised class
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}


  @Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory1")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
kafkaListenerContainerFactory1() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory1());
    return factory;
}

 @Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory2")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
kafkaListenerContainerFactory2() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory2());
    return factory;
}
```

***Step2:-***

- **@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class) =>
  Don't read the values from yml or properties file defined by spring.kafka @ConfigurationProperties**

***Step3:-***

```
 @KafkaListener(
            topics = "topic1",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory1" ,
            groupId = "com.groupid1")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord) throws InterruptedException {


        LOGGER.info("consuming from topic1 {}" , consumerRecord.value());
        Thread.sleep(1000000); //For testing

    }

 @KafkaListener(
            topics = "topic2",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory2" ,
            groupId = "com.groupid2")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord) throws InterruptedException {


        LOGGER.info("consuming from topic2 {}" , consumerRecord.value());
        Thread.sleep(1000000); //For testing

    }
```

Comment: General solution, can be also used to connect to different clusters for different topics. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer, obviously. But it might help someone else.

---

You don't need to create multiple ConsumerFactory Beans. You can do it without notifying class (`User` or `Event`) in the config i.e. `new JsonDeserializer<>(Event.class)` and add trusted package.

```java
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String,User> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("user.consumer.group"));
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,JsonDeserializer.class);

    // TODO: Remove "*" and add specific package name
    config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*"); // <<-- New config added

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);

}
```

While receiving the record:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics="${event.topic}")
void receiveUserRecord(User record){ ... } # For User POJO

@KafkaListener(topics="${event.topic}")
void receiveEventRecord(Event record){ ... } # For Event POJO
```